# BinaryWriter Unusual hex

Tags: c#, memorystream, binarywriter

I got some problem transfering Data via the BinaryWriter.

When I try to send

```
bw.Write(0x1a);
bw.Write(0xf8);
bw.Write(0x05);
```

It gets in the output to 0x00 - via

```
Client2Server._mainSock.Send(ms.ToArray());
```

What is causing this problem?

Greetings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are writing 3 **integers** here. Integers take 4 bytes, and in the cases shown, 3 of them are going to be zeros. Send bytes instead:

```
bw.Write((byte)0x1a);
```

of course, if you are writing bytes, then `BinaryWriter` is overkill - you could just use the `Stream`.